# How to free up memory allocated to nested numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-leaks

I have a super huge numpy array which memory allocated to it never gets free again. I simply demonstrate my situation so you can see the problem yourself.

Memory allocated to simple numpy arrays will immediately freed up after that variable can be remove (like below which I delete it):

```
import numpy as np

X = np.ones((40000, 40000))

X.nbytes
12800000000

del(X)
```

When I run the code above, all the 12 GB memory will free up immediately. But in case of nested numpy arrays things get complicated:

```
import numpy as np
import random

foo = np.array([np.array([np.ones((256,)) for j in range(random.randint(100, 150))]) for i in range(40000)])

sum(f.nbytes for f in foo)
10240481280

del(foo)
```

Now the 10 GB of memory will never gets freed even if you run `gc.collect()` explicitly. Do you guys have any clue?

**P.S**: The env: Ubuntu + Python 2.7 + numpy 1.15.1

Comment: perhaps you can try to flatten the array before deleting it.

Comment: @BinyaminEven It may work. It may have many workarounds but I'm looking for the reason behind this weird behavior.

Comment: Have you spent any time poring over the Numpy documentation? Can we rule that out?

Comment: @wwii This is not my actual code, It's just a minimal code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What system are you using? If I run `del(foo)` on my Win10 Anaconda Python 3.6, the memory frees up as it should.

Comment: @JohanL Well, interesting. I'm on Ubuntu/Python 2.7.

Comment: OK, and what version number for numpy (`numpy.__version__`)? I am at 1.14.3. To me, this seems like an issue with the numpy implementation.

Comment: @JohanL numpy version is 1.15.1

Comment: Work inside functions, and return only what you need... The rest will be garbage collected when you exit the function.

Comment: @Benjamin It simply doesn't. Actually my code is inside a function and I'm not really deleting the variable. I expected it to be freed up after the call but it doesn't.

Comment: OK, good to know because: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255371/when-am-i-supposed-to-use-del-in-python/39255472

Comment: On ubuntu 16.04 / Python 3.5 / numpy 1.13.1 and can confirm this same behavior.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27419153/2823755

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455048/releasing-memory-in-python makes me suspect this isn't a numpy specific issue.

Comment: Run your problematic code in a loop: if the memory doesn’t keep climbing, it’s not a leak but merely failure to return memory to the OS (which is common and complicated).

Comment: @DavisHerring well I tested and it doesn't climb any more. It seems a sever problem as it eats all available memory and then goes to swap ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Releasing memory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455048/releasing-memory-in-python)

Comment: @Mehraban: That memory will eventually all go to swap and stay there, causing no further performance problems.  But see the duplicate for a way around it.